# javascript: pick random item (as long as it's not already displayed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, random

I have a profile picture that I want to change onclick. I've created classes to change the background image of this element based on which class is applied, but I'm not sure how to do the comparison.

I know how to create the array of classes and how to pick a random class, I just don't know how to tell if the random class that was just picked is also the class which is already applied.

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
var randPick = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);
var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
$(this).removeClass(currentClass);
$(this).addClass(classes[randPick]);
```

How can I apply `$(this).addClass(classes[randPick]);` ONLY if `classes[randPick]` isn't the currently displayed class in `$(this).attr('class')`?

Comment: `if(currentClass !== classes[randPick]) $(this).addClass(classes[randPick]);` doesn't work?

Comment: I probably worded my question a little vague. I can do the comparison, but setting `var randPick` only runs the Math functions that one time as it's set. So, if the comparison comes back true then I guess I'd have to redeclare `var randPick` to re-run the Math functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
var randPick = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length-1)+1;
var temp = classes[0];
classes[0] = classes[randPick];
classes[randPick] = temp;
var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
$(this).removeClass(currentClass);
$(this).addClass(classes[0]);
```

This will randomly choose from `n-1` of the classes, then swap the random pick so that it is never used two times in a row. (But it could be used again, just not two times in a row.)

That is what it sounded like you wanted, is this correct? Never to have something show twice in a row / "the class which is already applied?"

If you wanted all of the classes to show in random order, and then start over again, again in a different random order, then you would use the other answer and simply reset your classes variable again after it had been emptied, with something like this:

```
originalClases = ['first', ..., 'fifth'];
if (classes.length == 0) classes = originalClasses;
/* followed by var randPick and the rest of the suggested code */
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. I'm pretty terrible at wording questions succinctly enough that people understand exactly what's in my head. However, with this solution i'm noticing that it seems to repeat the same class every once in a while. I thought maybe jQuery just wasn't catching the click() event, but it appears that it is. There also doesn't seem to be any particular ratio of success/fail in terms of changing the class. Roughly once every 20 clicks or so it shows the same class. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Yes, the same class might show again. Just not twice in a row. If you want to never have the same class show again, then use the second part of my answer together with Elliot's splice answer. This will destroy the array of classes one at a time, and then replace it again with the original full set of classes, thereby starting the whole random process again.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
$(this).addClass(classes[randPick]);
```

With this:

```
$(this).addClass(classes.splice(randPick, 1)[0]);
```

If you make `classes` a global variable, then every time you add a class to your element, it'll get removed from the list and won't be picked again.

Comment: This works great. Although, is there a way to make it repeat after cycling through all available array items, or is the array destroyed in the process?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass(currentClass))
$(this).addClass(classes[randPick]);
```